# Does IntelliSense feature available in Data Studio?

Tags: db2, windows, ibm-data-studio

Does IBM Data Studio have `IntelliSense features` or [Intelligent code completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_code_completion) something
like below?

I would like to write an SQL query with IntelliSense type functionality.

I have IBM Data Studio 4.1.3

Note: for getting quick help, I have also asked in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74097672/are-intellisense-features-available-in-data-studio)

[image: IntelliSense features]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in IBM Data Studio, as far as I know.  You may find something useful in the [IBM Database Add-Ins for Visual Studio](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=started-database-add-ins-visual-studio-overview) in the DB2 SQL Editor.